Что значат цветные уголки в элементах ввода в интерфейсе lsfusion?
А что значат красные и синие уголки в инпутах?



Красным уголком обозначаются поля ввода, значения в которых обязательно должны быть заданы, иначе нельзя будет применить изменения.

Синим уголком обозначаются поля ввода, значения которых можно изменить.


